# Convert complex<int16_t> to complex<double>

Tags: c++11, casting, complex-numbers

Is there anyway in C++11 to do this:

```
 std::complex<int16_t> integer(42,42);
 std::complex<double> doub(25.5,25.5);
 std::complex<double> answer = integer*doub;
```

The error is

```
error: no match for ‘operator*’ (operand types are    
‘std::complex<short     int>’ and ‘std::complex<double>’)
std::complex<double> answer = integer*doub;
```

I have tried static_cast like;

```
std::complex<double> answer = static_cast<std::complex<double>>(integer)*doub;
```

Comment: Note that the Standard does not require `std::complex<int16_t>` to work  in any meaningful way (only the three floating types have defined behaviour)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no predefined convertion from `complex<double>` to `complex<int16_t>` or viceversa.

You can define your own:

```
template <typename D, typename S> std::complex<D> cast(const std::complex<S> s)
{
    return std::complex<D>(s.real(), s.imag());
}

int main()
{
    std::complex<int16_t> integer(42, 42);
    std::complex<double> doub(25.5, 25.5);
    std::complex<double> answer = cast<double, int16_t>(integer)*doub;
}
```