# static_cast complex<short> to complex<double> in c++

Tags: c++, c++11, casting, eigen, static-cast

I would like to use static_cast to convert complex< short > to complex< double >.

[Convert complex<int16_t> to complex<double>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34219555/convert-complexint16-t-to-complexdouble)

I am trying to do the same thing as in this post, but I need to use static_cast. The reason I cannot use that solution is because I am using Eigen which uses static_cast in its cast() function. Is there a way to extend the functionality of static_cast to convert in this way? Or is there a way to extend Eigen's cast() function to handle this conversion?

This is basically what I am attempting:

```
Eigen::Array<std::complex<short>, Eigen::Dynamic, 1> short_array;
Eigen::Array<std::complex<double>, Eigen::Dynamic, 1> double_array;
double_array = short_array.cast< std::complex<double> >();
```

Comment: Note that the Standard does not require `std::complex<short>` to work  in any meaningful way (only the three floating types have defined behaviour)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest is to specialize `Eigen::internal::cast`:

```
template<>
inline std::complex<double> cast(const std::complex<short>& x) {
  return std::complex<double>(std::real(x),std::imag(x));
}
```

Demo [here](https://godbolt.org/g/NqbCLw).

Answer (score 6):

I'd do it without a `cast` function like this:

```
Eigen::Array<std::complex<short>, Eigen::Dynamic, 1> short_array;
Eigen::Array<std::complex<double>, Eigen::Dynamic, 1> double_array;
double_array = short_array.unaryExpr(ptr_fun(complex_cast<double, short>));
```

Where function for casting complex may look like this:

```
template<class T, class U>
std::complex<T> complex_cast(const std::complex<U> &c) {
    return { static_cast<T>(c.real()), static_cast<T>(c.imag()) };
}
```

Comment: The example function fails to compile as `compl` is keyword [1]  so cannot be used as a variable name. 
[1] https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/compl

Answer (score 3):

I've got no enlightning answer, I fear. You can extend `std::complex` to provide a conversion operator:

```
#include <complex>
#include <iostream>

template<class T, class U>
struct castable_complex : std::complex<T>
{
    castable_complex() = default;
    castable_complex(T real, T imag) : std::complex<T>(real, imag) {}
    // more constructed needed I guess...

    operator std::complex<U>() const
    {
        return { static_cast<U>(this->real()), static_cast<U>(this->imag()) };
    }
};

int main()
{
    auto z = castable_complex<double, int> { 3.14, 1.618 };
    auto w = static_cast<std::complex<int>>(z);
    std::cout << "w = " << w.real() << " + i." << w.imag() << "\n";
}
```

Demo: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c38fe81c92d8664e

Comment: If you want to cast back, you need to make `w` a `castable_complex<int, double>`.